# Point domain name registered with Godaddy and administered on XYZ server to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, domain-name, dns-hosting, dns-zone

There is **domain** e.g example.com registered with Godaddy, **hosted** on `SomeHosting` service (The server which serves the contents is here). This same hosting company provides the DNS Zone editor (cPanel) with following (sample) entries

```
ns1.example.com.            A   IP_1
ns2.example.com.            A   IP_2
example.com.                A   IP_3
mail.example.com.           A   IP_2
www.example.com.            CNAME   example.com
ftp.example.com.            A   IP_2
cpanel.example.com.         A   IP_2
east.example.com.           A   IP_1
west.example.com.           A   IP_1
test.example.com.           A   IP_2
qa.example.com.             A   x.x.x.x
special.example.com.          CNAME some-load-balancer.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
```

I want to get rid of this SomeHosting company (**not Godady**) and want to move to AWS. So I created instances and beanstalks etc on AWS and they are working fine.
I want that now when some one type example.com, It should point to my load balancer(ELB) on AWS.

So after reading some tutorail, In AWS's Route 53 console, I created a hosted zone with **example.com.**, it automatically added 2 records

```
example.com.    NS  ns-xxxx.awsdns-37.co.uk.
                    ns-xxx.awsdns-29.net.
                    ns-xxxx.awsdns-14.org.
                    ns-xx.awsdns-03.com.

example.com.        SOA ns-xxxx.awsdns-37.co.uk. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600 86400
```

**Please confirm following questions with Yes/No following details if any**

1. My first confusion is, should I copy only **4** entries from **NS** record to Godaddy configuration?
2. Where and how I will map example.com to take user to Elastic Load balancer (my-loadbalancer.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com) By creating a new Recordset in same hosted zone?
3. I need to move email to Google Apps, I think, it will require MX record (in same hosted zone)?
4. Is that every thing I require to leave my old hosting company and switch to AWS (though not leaving Godaddy) ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use Route 53 with your EC2 instance, you can use GoDaddy's DNS system. This is included in your fees, and is simpler than Route 53. In this case you just change the A records and CNAMEs to point to your new AWS IP address (whether that's Elastic Load Balancer, Elastic IP Address, or if you're foolish your default public IP address), MX entries to point to Google.

Route 53 is probably faster and more reliable than GoDaddy, but they charge for it - not much though. If you move to Route 53, NS records are informational only, you set these in Godaddy. You'd simply set your A record or CNAME to point to your ELB (I can't remember which you need), and obviously your MX to point to Google.

Amazon has step by step documentation around DNS and ELB that you can follow [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-getting-started.html). Their higher level documentation on Route 53 is [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-to-aws-resources.html).

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of your website to any server totally depends on your domain control panel.

Your Name-Servers defines that where is your zone file located.

Lets say you have purchased domain from Go-daddy, they have provided you with domain control panel where by default you are assigned with default name servers of Go-daddy. So in this case you just need to enter the value of:

```
A records
CNAME records
MX records
```

In your domain control panel only. By doing this you can resolve your request to the place where you want it to go actually, weather its **somehosting** or **AWS**

---

Second Case is where you dont have the default name servers of Go-daddy, you have added the name servers of your hosting provider in your domain control panel, then you have to first remove the Name-Servers records of your old hosting provider and either you can use default name servers of Go-daddy or your new hosting provider.

### But keep in mind if you use default name servers of Go-daddy then you have modify the entries of A,Cname,MX records in domain control panel only or, if you are using the name-servers of your hosting provider then you have to modify other records(A,Cnamw,MX) in the dns zone provided by your host provider.